# Get all the members below me in an mlm module in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, while-loop

I have a database, as shown in this, any user can join with any sponsor ID, and they will get their own user ID which can lead the tree further. I want to get details of a particular `user_id`, say, '2'. I am expecting the output in which the `user_id` will be (`3,4` since `3` is directly linked with `2` and `4` is linked directly with `3` which is linked with `2`). Similarly if I select `user_id` `1`, then I would get the resultant `user_id` (`2,3,4,5`, where `2` and `5` are directly linked to `user_id` `1` and `3,4` are indirectly linked to `1`).

I have tried almost every possible `while` loop format, but I just can't get the output. Here is the final bit of my code, because I have deleted most of it:

```php
<?php
include 'config.php';
$current_user='1';

$all = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users");
while($all_array = mysqli_fetch_array($all)){
    $all_sponsors = $all_array['sponsor_id'];
}

$below_details = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE sponsor_id ='$current_user'");
while ($below_array = mysqli_fetch_array($below_details)){
    $below_users = $below_array['user_id']; 
    }
?>
```

Any kind of help is appreciated. Feel free to ask me the details if there is any confusion in the question.

[image: phpMyAdmin information]

Comment: Storing tree structures in relational databases is [always a pain](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/storing-tree-in-rdb).

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](https://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [recursive CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive-hierarchy-traversal) to retrieve all the members below a given id -

```
WITH RECURSIVE pyramid AS (
    SELECT u.* FROM users u WHERE sponsor_id = 1 /* starting sponsor_id */
    UNION ALL
    SELECT u.* FROM pyramid p JOIN users u ON p.id = u.sponsor_id
)
SELECT * FROM pyramid;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...I don't know who u r but there is one thing for sure....u are awesome 

Comment: This query is perfect for localhost but it's not working online...can u help

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? Common Table Expressions were added in MySQL 8.0 (MySQL 8.0.11 - 2018-04-19, General Availability)

Comment: That doesn't matters tbh because whatever version I am changing online it still shows the same error...

Comment: What error do you get and what code are you using? The version does matter as this query requires MySQL 8.

Comment: Unrecognized statement type. (near "WITH" at position 0) <- This is the error I am getting when I am running the code online. Its Working quite fine on localhost though

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "running the code online". Is this a reference to an account with a shared hosting provider? It may be that you need to select the MySQL version before creating the database. Just changing the selected MySQL version is unlikely to move an existing database to a different instance.